# Area of a triangle from vector coordinates of vertices in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles

I have three vectors $v_1, v_2$, and $v_3$, giving the vertices of a triangle. The $z$-coordinates are the same, so the $(x,y)$-coordinates alone give the vertices of an identical triangle in the $xy$-plane. Is there a general way to find the area of this triangle given the vectors?

$$
v_1 = (v_{x1}, v_{y1}, v_{z1}) \\
v_2 = (v_{x2}, v_{y2}, v_{z2}) \\
v_3 = (v_{x3}, v_{y3}, v_{z3})
$$

?

Comment: @Blue Yes, sorry for the wrong term

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \Delta &=
  \frac{1}{2}|(\mathbf{v}_{1}-\mathbf{v}_{3}) \times
              (\mathbf{v}_{2}-\mathbf{v}_{3})| \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} |\mathbf{v}_{1} \times \mathbf{v}_{2}+
                  \mathbf{v}_{2} \times \mathbf{v}_{3}+
                  \mathbf{v}_{3} \times \mathbf{v}_{1}|
\end{align*}

Comment: It's much easier than I thought. We just find the area of $1/2$ of the area of the parallelogram determined by vectors $v_1-v_3$ and $v_2-v_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: As per your assumption, if you consider the triangle to lay entirely in 2D, and the vectors represent coordinates of each vertex, then see this reference (has animation too):
[Area of triangle in 2D](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordtrianglearea.html).

For a vector form, see:
[Triangle-Area-2d-VectorForm.](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/MOW/vectors/vectors-11/v-11-7.html)

Answer (score 1):

Its just $1/2 a\times b$ ie cross product. Where a represents vector from $v_2$ to $v_3$ and b represents vector from $v_2$ to $v_1$ so its vector area $A=1/2(v_2-v_3)\times (v_2-v_1)$ and its area in units is just the |..| of vector area.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ and $b$ are the vectors for two sides then you can reduce the above answers to $\dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{|a|^2|b|^2 - (a\cdot b)^2}$ with the advantage that it works in any dimension.