# Area of triangle determined by three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given vectors $a = (2, 1, 3)$, $b = (4, 1, 2)$, $c = (1, -1, 5)$, need to find the area of the triangle $abc$ determined by the three vectors (the vectors are the vertices of the triangle).

My solution:

$A = 1/2 \text{(base)(height)}$. Take base $d := a-b = (-2, 0, 1)$. Need to find the shortest (perpendicular) distance from $c$ to the line determined by $L := a + td$ ($t\in \mathbb{R}$). $L = (2,1,3)+t(-2,0,1)$, thus we need to find $x = (2-2t,1, 3+t)$. We need $x\cdot d = 0$, so $t=1/5$ and $x=(3/5,1,16/5)$. We have that height $h:=c-x=(2/5,-2,9/5)$, so $\vert h \vert = \sqrt{37/5}$, and also $\vert d \vert = \sqrt{5}$. Hence, the area is $A = 1/2 * 37/5 * \sqrt{5}=\frac{37}{{2\sqrt{5}}}$.

Please let me know if you think my solution is correct. I'd like to make sure that I didn't make some conceptual mistake(s).

Comment: Are you sure these aren't the _vertices_ of the triangle?  As vectors, they don't seem to be coplanar, in which case it's going to be kind of tough to make a triangle with them...  (In fact, they don't make a triangle:  a closed triangle would require the sum of three _vectors_ to equal zero.)

Comment: Yes, these are vertices. I've edited the post to make this more precise, sorry.

Comment: Have you had the vector/cross product yet?  If so, find the two vectors that emanate from any one vertex to the other two.  There is a simple relation involving the "cross product" that will give you the area of the triangle. (Also, I don't see _how_ you got the difference between $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ to give you the result you show.)

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct the arithmetic errors. But what do you think about my solution approach? I'd be interested in seeing your approach as well.

Comment: @sequence See my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676971/area-of-a-triangle-from-vector-coordinates-of-vertices-in-3d/1676979#1676979

Comment: Your base vector is alright now, but you need a perpendicular vector that runs from that base to the opposite vertex, $ \ (1, \ -1, \ 5) \ $ .  Presently your altitude for the triange is not correct.

Comment: I guess I was typing too fast, as well as made arithmetic errors. But my approach appears to be OK. I'd like to see yours if you don't mind. There doesn't seem to be much geometry on this website.

Comment: You should have $ \ h \ \cdot \ d \ = \ 0 \ $ ; $ \ x \ $ is just a point on the base.  You will need to re-calculate $ \ t \ $ because the area you're getting is still incorrect.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, yes, that's another inattention error. Thanks for pointing it out. I tend to do that, unfortunately, much more frequently than I should. On a different note, Ng Chung Tak's solution is very simple, I also commented on it in the thread where he posted it. Much simpler.

Comment: You want $$ \ \vec{h} \ \cdot \ \vec{d} \ = \ \langle \ 1 - ( 2+2t) \ , \ (-1) - 1 \ , \ 5 - (3 - t) \ \rangle \ \cdot \ \langle \ -2 \ , \ 0 \ , \ 1 \ \rangle \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$  You should find $ \ t \ = \ -\frac{4}{5} \ $ and a length for the height of $ \ h \ = \ \sqrt{\frac{29} {5}} \ . $  By two other methods, the area of the triangle is also found to be $ \ \frac{1}{2} \ \sqrt{29} \ $ .

Answer (score 2):

I would’ve gone with the cross product approach suggested in the comments (see below), but here’s how I’d do it using your approach.

By taking the base of the triangle as $d=a-b$, we’re effectively translating the origin to $b$. To find the altitude, we need the component of $e=c-b$ that is orthogonal to $d$, i.e., the orthogonal rejection of $e$ relative to $d$. The orthogonal projection of $e$ onto $d$ is $${e\cdot d\over d\cdot d}d=\frac9 5(-2,0,1)=\left(\frac{18}5,0,\frac95\right),$$ and the orthogonal rejection is $e$ minus this vector, i.e., $\left(\frac35,-2,\frac65\right)$. The area of the triangle is then $$A=\frac12\|(-2,0,1)\|\cdot\left\|\left(\frac35,-2,\frac65\right)\right\|=\frac12\cdot\sqrt{5}\cdot{\sqrt{145}\over5}={\sqrt{29}\over2}.$$ You can also find the altitude by finding the nearest point on the line $a+td$ to $c$, as you do, by solving $(c-a-td)\cdot d=0$ for $t$. You’ll find that when you substitute the value of $t$ that you get back into $c-a-td$, you’ll end up with the same vector as above.

Alternatively, the norm of the cross product of two vectors is the area of the parallelogram defined by those vectors, so we have for the triangle $$A=\frac12\|d\times e\| = \frac12\|(2,3,4)\|={\sqrt{29}\over 2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use one of the trigonometric versions for the area of a triangle , $ \ A \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ a \ b \ \sin \theta \ $ , where $ \ \theta \ $ is the included angle between the given sides.  You can pick any two of the vector lengths to use for $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ , say , $ \ \langle \ 2, \ 0, \ -1 \ \rangle \ $ (with length $ \ \sqrt{5} \ $ ) and $ \ \langle \ -1  , \ -2 , \ 2 \ \rangle \ $ (with length $ \ 3 \ $ ) .  The *cosine* of the included angle is given by $ \ \frac{\vec{a} \ \cdot \ \vec{b} }{a \ b } \ $ , so the "Pythagorean Identity" gives the *sine* of this angle as $$ \ \frac{\sqrt{a^2b^2 \ - \ (\vec{a} \ \cdot \vec{b})^2}}{a \ b} \ \ ;  $$
the area of the triangle is then $ \ A \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ \sqrt{a^2b^2 \ - \ (\vec{a} \ \cdot \vec{b})^2} \ $ .  We find the dot product of our chosen vectors to be $ \ -4 \ $ (the triangle is obtuse) , and the area as

$$ \ A \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ \sqrt{(\sqrt{5})^2  \cdot 3^2 \ - \ (-4)^2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{2} \ \sqrt{5 \cdot 9 \ - \ 16} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{2} \ \sqrt{29} \ \ . $$

Answer (score 0):

You could use Heron's Formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

[image]

Convert the vertex vectors into three edge vectors. Then compute length of each edge. Use that to find the semi-perimeter. Plug in into the formula.

I find it easiest to use vector manipulation when the co-ordinates are non-planar.

```
a<-c(2,1,3)
b<-c(4,1,2)
c<-c(1,-1,5)

s1<-b-a
s2<-c-b
s3<-a-c

s1.length<-norm(s1,type="2")
s2.length<-norm(s2,type="2")
s3.length<-norm(s3,type="2")

p<-(s1.length+s2.length+s3.length)/2
sqrt(p*(p-s1.length)*(p-s2.length)*(p-s3.length))
```

I get Area as 2.692582.